# attempting to initialize php variables in constructor, getting error

Tags: php, class, constructor

I'm trying to initialize a class attribute within a php constructor method, but am getting the error:

Notice: Undefined variable: _board in C:\wamp\scaleUp\back\objects.php on line 9

code:

```
<?php
class Board {
public function __construct(){
    for ($x = 9; $x >= 0; $x--) {
        for ($y = 0; $y<10; $y++){
            $row = array();
            $row[$y] = $y;
        }
        $this->$_board = array(); 
            $this->$_board[$x] = $row;
    }
    echo "here";
    echo $this->$board[$x];
}       

 }

 $board =  new Board();

 ?>
```

Comment: This is a typo question.  Your code is unnecessarily complex for future Stack Overflow readers, so here is a later asked dupe that is easier on the eyes: [Failing to assign value for public property in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24495806/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to access an object field is `$obj->field`, not `$obj->$field` (unless you want to access the field name that is stored in `$field`).

Answer (score 1):

remove the `$` from `_board` -

```
$this->_board = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have debugged the code for you.

```
<?php
class Board {
public $_board;
public function __construct(){
    for ($x = 9; $x >= 0; $x--) {
        for ($y = 0; $y<10; $y++){
            $row = array();
            $row[$y] = $y;
        }
        $this->_board = array(); 
            $this->_board[$x] = $row;
    }
    echo "here";
    echo $this->_board[$x+1];/*OR*/print_r($this->_board[$x+1]);
    //$x had to be incremented here.
}       

 }

 $board =  new Board();

 ?>
```

As others mentioned, you have to follow the syntax: `$obj->property`, not `$obj->$property`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`$this->board`

You don't need the second `$` sign.

Also, in your constructor, in the inner loop, you are re-initializing `$row` as an array in every iteration. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your variable as a member variable 
suck as

```
class object {
 $_board ;
...
...
...
}
```

and when you want to use it you have to use the following syntax

```
$this->_board = .....;
```

I hope this helps you