# Failing to assign value for public property in constructor

Tags: php, class, object, authentication, constructor

```
<?php 
$login1 = new Login("cam", "1234"); echo "<br>";
echo $login1->authenticate($login1->name, $login1->this->password);

class Login{
     public $name;
     public $password;

    function Login($u, $w){
        $this->name = $u;
        $this->$password = $w;
    }

    function authenticate($name, $password){
        $lookupusername = "cam"; 
        $lookuppassword = "1234";
        if($name == $lookupusername && $password == $lookuppassword){
            return "Login Success";
            echo "Login Success";
        }   else {
                return "Login Fail";
                echo "Login Fail";
            }
    }
}
?>
```

I am new to PHP. I am wondering why the constructor in my login class is not setting the string literals as the name and password properties of the class. I tried a set() method and that didn't work either. I also tried assigning the string literals as variables and passing them in by reference. Nope. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This `$this->$password` is wrong, remove the `$` from `$password`

Comment: Also this `$login1->this->password` is wrong, change it to `$login1->password`

Comment: Oh, seems like small typo errors. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't build a constructor in the same way that Java does (which is what your example appears to be based on). You'll want to use PHP's [`__construct`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) method, like below:

```
public function __construct($u, $w) {
    $this->name = $u;
    $this->password = $w;
}
```

Also, your way of accessing the `name` attribute is correct, but `password` is incorrect. Use `$this->password` instead of `$this->$password`, and `$login1->password` instead of `$login1->this->password`

Comment: One more thing: When I make a constructor, does the default constructor still work? If so, how do I disable objects being made without parameters?

Comment: @Cameronc56 - It does not work cleanly (you'll get warnings); what you can do instead is use default parameters (`function __construct($a = null, $b = null) {`)